# How to add button,label and an image to multiple viewcontrollers using tabbarconrtoller

Tags: xcode, uiviewcontroller, uiimageview, uibutton, uitabbarcontroller

Im using a tabbarcontroller which leads to 5 viewcontrollers when each tabs selected.
I need to a add button,image and label which are common for all viewcontrollers.Is there any possible way to add these into tabbarconrtoller, so that i don't have to add these to each viewcontroller individually.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a seperate view for your button, image and label, and then add it as a subview in all your view controllers.